# Calculating a Week Ending Date from a date in a Postgresql database - ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone + double precision

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, isodate

I have a table (loads) in Postgresql database that has a TimeStamp data type column (ship_date).  I can figure out the day of the week by using the isodow but need to add this to the date in the ship_date column to come up with a "week ending date".

What we are trying to do in general
loads.ship_date + (6 - extract(isodow from loads.ship_date))

What we are needing
Wednesday           Saturday (weekending)
6/30/2021 + 6 - 3 = 7/3/2021

We are getting the following error
ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone + double precision;

Answer (score 1):

Use date_trunc to the first day of the week (iso), then add interval 6 days to get the last date of the week.

```
select date_trunc('week', now()) + interval '6 days';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some type casts. Using `localtimestamp` for your `loads.ship_date`, that would be

```
SELECT localtimestamp::date + 6 -
       extract(dow FROM localtimestamp)::integer;

  ?column?  
════════════
 2021-07-03
(1 row)
```

It is a questionable idea to call a column of type `timestamp` `ship_date`.